# How can I check If sublicensing a game to someone is not subject to cheating?

Tags: unity, google-play, appstore, payment

Basically I have a game, but here In Italy I need to subscribe to Commercial Chamber just to start selling (3000€/year). So my idea was to let a friend sell the game on the AppStore/PlayStore/Windows store using his accounts. **He will instead pay me after keeping a royalty on the revenue.** Or at least this seems to become the contract (if you are actually italian and can give me hints on this topic it would greatly appreciated)

Is there any tool available to various stores so I can check the income of my apps even if sold by third parties (the idea is to be sure he takes only the royalty we previously agreed on). In example: enable my account to become developer account so I can test In-App purchases with my account, and then sell the apps with the account of my friend.

One idea was to use analytics tools, but that's unviable:

- If the app get cracked analytics tools will not show correct results (and hackers can easily remove analytics too so).
- If my friend has to access source code/ Unity project file he could remove any tracking code (he need to have that access, because he have to setup license Keys on each build anyway).

Thanks.

Comment: appfigures.com he can set you up with access to sales figures.

Comment: If it cracks wouldn't it just be pirated anyway and not contribute to sales? Does he have the technical knowledge to remove the analytics code or modify such that only a subset actually are forwarded to the analytics reporting site?

Comment: Yes he has technical knowledge (he owns a small IT company). Infact pirated apps may direct me to believe he cheated while in reality he may have not cheated. That's why analytics are not reliable, because analytics may come from pirated apps. It is strange that various stores do not allow to share "income view" for particular apps (or if that is allowed I just don't know how to do), the only value I will trust is the one the store tells to me.

Comment: You really should not make revenue sharing deals with people you don't trust. When you don't want to be cheated, sell the game to him for a fixed sum.

Comment: If it's a flat rate (eg, no in-app transactions), you could use the total install number, price, and fees to calculate an estimate of how much he should be paying you. Or, you could ask him to create a new google account just for selling the game and giving you the password and stuff to it then have him under contract to not change the password or something? I feel like this is very gray area stuff within legal contexts though and if your country sees all this money rolling in an no taxes/commercial chamber subscription you might get audited.